# Simple Product Thumbnail in minicart/checkout

Tags: magento2, php

In Sales => Checkout => Shopping Cart

I have set "Grouped Product Image" and "Configurable Product Image" to "Product Thumbnail Itself"

This works fine in the cart page.

But in the minicart and checkout its trying to display the simple item thumbnail instead of parent, is there a configuration I have missed?